# Remove ajax.googleapis.com from my Wordpress site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, google-api

Any reference to googleapis will block my website in China. How can I remove these references?

Here are the results of my grep search for google api reference:

```
./codesearch.php:$command = "grep -ri 'ajax.googleapis.com' ./*"; ./wp-content/cache/all/privacy-policy/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/privacy-policy/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/contact/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/contact/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/author/boomerlanglearning/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/author/boomerlanglearning/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/my-account/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/my-account/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/my-account/lost-password/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/my-account/lost-password/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/terms-and-conditions/index.html: ./wp-content/cache/all/terms-and-conditions/index.html: ./wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-checkout-manager/woocommerce-checkout-manager.php: // wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-lib', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js' ); ./wp-content/plugins/booster-plus-for-woocommerce/includes/settings/wcj-settings-general.php:   'default' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', ./wp-content/plugins/booster-plus-for-woocommerce/includes/classes/class-wcj-scripts.php:  $datepicker_css_path = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'; ./wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-bookings/woocommerce-bookings.php:  wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-style', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/' . $jquery_version . '/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css' ); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php: $scripts->add( 'prototype', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js', array(), '1.7.1'); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php: $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-root', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/scriptaculous.js', array('prototype'), '1.9.0'); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php:   $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-builder', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/builder.js', array('scriptaculous-root'), '1.9.0'); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php: $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-dragdrop', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/dragdrop.js', array('scriptaculous-builder', 'scriptaculous-effects'), '1.9.0'); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php:   $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-effects', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/effects.js', array('scriptaculous-root'), '1.9.0'); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php: $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-slider', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/slider.js', array('scriptaculous-effects'), '1.9.0'); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php:    $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-sound', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/sound.js', array( 'scriptaculous-root' ), '1.9.0' ); ./wp-includes/script-loader.php:  $scripts->add( 'scriptaculous-controls', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.9.0/controls.js', array('scriptaculous-root'), '1.9.0'); Grep job over.
```

Here is the code I added to the functions.php file of my child theme:

```
function modify_jquery() {
if (!is_admin()) {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js', false, '1.9.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
   add_action('init', 'modify_jquery');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` should do the job for the non-admin front end as you require.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'modify_jquery', 99);
function modify_jquery(){
  wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery');
  wp_deregister_script( 'jquery');   
  wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js', false, '1.9.0');
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  // repeat for your other googleapi scripts
}
```

Above is modified from your code - but in my case script dereg/reg and "do late" priority of 99 was unnecessary (see below).

Your grep output includes scripts which may have **dependencies** e.g. 'jquery' AND **stylesheets**. I'm not wading through through your grep; but the following is a cut and paste job example of dequeing stylesheets and handling script dependencies in child functions.php for Hemingway theme.

```
function dequeue_unnecessary_fonts() {
  wp_dequeue_style( 'hemingway_googleFonts-css' );
  wp_deregister_style( 'hemingway_googleFonts-css' );
  wp_dequeue_style( 'hemingway_googleFonts' );
  wp_deregister_style( 'hemingway_googleFonts' );
}
// add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'dequeue_unnecessary_fonts',20 );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_unnecessary_fonts',20 );
// wp_print_styles (still) works for me (it can affect admin styles)
// but post WP3.3 the Codex recommends using  above style functions with wp_enqueue_scripts instead


function hem_script_fix() {
  wp_dequeue_script( 'hemingway_global' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'hemingway_global', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/global.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
  // identifies script is dependent on jquery which must be "loaded" earlier
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hem_script_fix' );
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this.

Comment: Hi youloveenglish glad it was of use. If it worked for you can you mark this as the correct answer thanks